# How to batch insert into hbase using saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

just learn spark for a while， i found the api: saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset when i use hbase, code like below， as far as know，this code can insert one row at a time , how to change it to batch put?  i am a rookie ..please help...tks

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put  
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable  
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat  
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result  
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes  
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job  
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}  

 /** 
 *
 */  
object HbaseTest2 {  

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseTest").setMaster("local")  
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)  

    val tablename = "account"  

    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","slave1,slave2,slave3")  
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")  
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tablename)  

    val job = Job.getInstance(sc.hadoopConfiguration)  
    job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable])  
    job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[Result])  
    job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])  

    val indataRDD = sc.makeRDD(Array("1,jack,15","2,Lily,16","3,mike,16"))  

    val rdd = indataRDD.map(_.split(',')).map{arr=>{  
      val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(arr(0)))  
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(1)))  
      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("age"),Bytes.toBytes(arr(2).toInt))  
      (new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)  
    }}  

    rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration())  

    sc.stop()  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to worry about this - under the hood, `put(Put)` and `put(List<Put>)` are identical. They both buffer messages and flush them in batches. There should be no noticeable performance difference.

I'm afraid the other answer is misguided.

Answer (score 0):

saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset performs single put.

To perform bulk put to hbase table, you can use hbase-spark connector.
The connector executes bulkPutFunc2 within mapPartition() so is efficient.
Your source code will change like below -

```
object HBaseTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseTest").setMaster("local")
        val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val tablename = "account"

    val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "slave1,slave2,slave3")
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    hbaseConf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase")

    val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, hbaseConf)

    val indataRDD = sc.makeRDD(Array("1,jack,15", "2,Lily,16", "3,mike,16"))

    hbaseContext.bulkPut(indataRDD, TableName.valueOf(tablename), bulkPutFunc2)

    sc.stop()
}
def bulkPutFunc2(arrayRec : String): Put = {
    val rec = arrayRec.split(",")
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rec(0).toInt))
    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("name"), Bytes.toBytes(rec(1)))
    put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("age"), Bytes.toBytes(rec(2).toInt))

    put
    }

}
```

pom.xml would have following entry -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-cdh5.12.1</version>
<dependency>
```

Comment: This answer misses the fact that under the hood, `put(Put)` and `put(List<Put>)` are the same. They both buffer messages and flush them in batches. There should be no noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @BenWatson your point is valid but this solution is more from perspective of optimized ingestion from Spark to HBase rather than put vs put(List<put>),
I have asked to use bulkPut from hbase-spark connector which internally uses mapPartition() instead of map() and hence eliminates the need to establish connection per record by creating one connection per partition.